# Google Translating a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, google-translate

I would like to translate a column entitled  TranslatedText within my pandas data-frame using the google translate package, where it detects the language and converts it to english. I have tried the code below. Loading and encoding the file work correctly however I keep receiving the following error at the translation stage:

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
import pandas as pd
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

file = r'file_path.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,encoding="ISO-8859-1")


df['TranslatedText'] = df['TranslatedText'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src='auto', dest='en').text )

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems incomplete

1. df is not defined
2. pandas module is not imported

I tested this same code , by importing pandas module and a sample dictionary and found that it is working.

```py
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

translator = Translator()
langdict = {0: {'English': 'Hello', 'Japanese': 'こんにちは'}, 1: {'English': 'Thanks', 'Japanese': 'ありがとう'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(langdict).T
df['TranslatedText'] = df['Japanese'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src='auto', dest='en').text )
print(df)
```

| English | Japanese | TranslatedText |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | こんにちは | Hello |
| Thanks | ありがとう | Thank You |

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my post inclusive of the df definition and pandas module, which I had forgot to mention. That being said when I run the function on the column it still gives the same error.